# The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it error

Tags: python, django

I got an error:

```
  ...
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'django.urls' from '/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I recently updated from Django 1.8 to 2.0, so I think that's why the error happens. I think urls.py causes this error, so I rewrote it like

```
from django.urls import include, path

app_name = 'App'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),

 ] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but the same error happens. I really cannot understand why this error happens. How should I fix this? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The error says,

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'django.urls' from '/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Could you please check your `envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py` if it has content like the following:

```
from .base import (
    clear_script_prefix, clear_url_caches, get_script_prefix, get_urlconf,
    is_valid_path, resolve, reverse, reverse_lazy, set_script_prefix,
    set_urlconf, translate_url,
)
from .exceptions import NoReverseMatch, Resolver404
from .resolvers import (
    LocaleRegexProvider, LocaleRegexURLResolver, RegexURLPattern,
    RegexURLResolver, ResolverMatch, get_ns_resolver, get_resolver,
)
from .utils import get_callable, get_mod_func

__all__ = [
    'LocaleRegexProvider', 'LocaleRegexURLResolver', 'NoReverseMatch',
    'RegexURLPattern', 'RegexURLResolver', 'Resolver404', 'ResolverMatch',
    'clear_script_prefix', 'clear_url_caches', 'get_callable', 'get_mod_func',
    'get_ns_resolver', 'get_resolver', 'get_script_prefix', 'get_urlconf',
    'is_valid_path', 'resolve', 'reverse', 'reverse_lazy', 'set_script_prefix',
    'set_urlconf', 'translate_url',
]
```

If it does not then that is the problem, else you're using circular imports somewhere i.e., in file1.py you're doing an `from file2 import var2` and in file2.py you're doing `from file1 import var1`.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting below line your code

`path('app/', include('app.urls')),`

this must be the cause of circular import issue. please reply if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
path('App/', include('App.urls')),